# Как получить из коллекции по ключю name? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить из коллекции по ключю name? Laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
$parties = Party::all();
$collection = $parties->get('name');

dd($parties, $collection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллекция это массив объектов, пройдитесь по нему циклом и работайте с каждым элементом как с объектом.
Исходя с вашего скрина я предполагаю что `attributes` это приватное свойство, значит для него должен быть геттер

```
foreach($parties as $party){
    echo $party->getAttributes()['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$collection = $parties->get('0')['name'];

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]